# Is it possible to transpile vanilla JavaScript in VS 2019?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2019

[Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/javascript-in-vs-2017?view=vs-2019) tells us that in order to write modern JavaScript and transpile it you should use TypeScript.

We don't use TypeScript in our company (a corporate technology choice decision) thus we only write JavaScript.

Is it possible to write pure JavaScript files (`.js` not `.ts`) and still use modern language features like lambda in VS 2019?

Comment: [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) with NodeJS or on the web? Or are you looking for an addon for Visual Studio the IDE with its built in JavaScript runtime?

Comment: TypeScript is a transpiler anyway, so it too can transpile code into older versions. But you don't require TypeScript to transpile JS, there are other tools that do JS → JS transpilation…

Comment: @Samathingamajig, yeah I know Babel and NodeJS support that. I just want to know if VS 2019 supports it out of the box or not. After all, it's a full-featured IDE and one expect it to support the most widespread language.

Comment: @deceze, thank you for the hint. Do you know any such tools? I tried Web Compiler, but it does not transpile `export` and `import`. In other words, it does not gather all of my files into the parent importer of all.

Comment: Well, yeah, Babel would be it. I don't know about VS integration specifically though.